# Play framework 2.5 with spring integration

Tags: java, spring, playframework

I'm migrating a project from Play 2.3 to 2.4, and further 2.5. I am struggling to integrate Spring with Play 2.4.

In Play 2.3 we have `getControllerInstance` method to manage controller injection and resolve the dependency by Spring application context and feel free to work with `@Autowired` and `@PersistentContext`.

However, in Play +2.4 trying to integrate spring-jpa and controller injection using Spring is very difficult.

Please provide any solution or alternate to use Play with Spring integration. `applicationContext` is Spring application context.

In Play 2.3 to inject controller by application context:

```
@override
public <A> A getBean(Class<A> clazz) {
    return ctx.getBean(clazz);
}
```

Where `ctx` is Spring `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: Formatting, clarification.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/remithieblin/play-spring-loader